# how to detect change in hour of system time

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program in Python that beeps every hour. and no of beeps should be equal to no of hours. such as for 12 o'clock it should beep 12 times.

but I have no idea how to detect change in hour.

```
def bep(h):
    for i in range(h):
        winsound.Beep(2000,800)
        sleep(2)
```

the above code beeps for h no of times and

```
def hour():
    return hour=int(time.ctime(time.time()).split()[3].split(':')[0])
```

it gives the hour.
but how to detect that hour has changed.

whether should I check every regular time interval and use previous hour and current hour to detect changes? I think this idea is not effective. because of time delay of interval time i.e.
check current time every 5 second and compare two successive check to detect change in hours.
is there any method to accomplish it directly.

Comment: Take a look at `sched` module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html. Also you can get the current hour using `datetime.now().hour`.

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest:

```
import datetime
import time
current = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    if datetime.datetime.now().hour != current:
        current = datetime.datetime.now().hour
        print "beep" , str(current)
```

Note you can test the code by using .minute rather than .hour Which will allow you to see if it fits your purposes.
You will have to replace the `print "beep", str(current)` with a call to your function `bep(current)`

Also you might want to consider adding a little extra code to your `bep(h)` function.

```
if h>12: h=h-12
if h == 0: h = 12
```

To ensure that for example: at 16:00 you only hear 4 beeps rather than 16 and at midnight, you hear 12 beeps, rather than none.

Comment: does this piece of code checks continuously the change in hour and notifies when hour has changed? it can be used for my script with simple modification if datetime.datetime.now().minute == 0: #call function that beeps and wait for a minute to avoid rechecking and evaluating if expression True and calling the beep function. am i right?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now().minute == 0` might ,not be the best check. I would rather  do like in this answer `datetime.datetime.now().minute != current` but with `.hour` instead of `.minute`. I guess @rolf-of-saxony did it per minute not to have to wait for an hour while testing

Comment: @BibekGhimire As Maarten suggested and I had supposed that I had made explicit, I used `.minute` purely for testing purposes. You should use `.hour`. I'll edit the answer.